# Cast problem in mysql via odbc and delphi

Tags: mysql, delphi

I'm debugging an old application in Delphi 5, connected with a recent version of MySql via ODBC connector. When using a CAST conversion function, even the following query:

`select cast(1 as char)`

returns an empty column without column name.
If I run the query directly into the mysql query analyzer it runs fine, so I suppose the problem is in the ODBC connector or in BDE.

Answer (score 0):

The only information I can find on this is [**this**](http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=33808) (emphasis mine):

> Connector/ODBC **erroneously** reported that it supported the CAST() and CONVERT() ODBC
>   functions for parsing values in SQL statements, which could lead to bad SQL generation
>   during a query.

Could it be that the connector does not support CAST at all?

Comment: It could be, but it's the last version, downloaded from the mysql site. I don't know. In order to isolate the problem, i'll move the cast to a view in the database.

Answer (score 0):

Try creating a stored procedure in the database to perform the CAST and hide it from ODBC.